# How do I best handle returning a specific object depending on certain conditions when there's no real "else" case to cover everything?

Tags: swift, language-agnostic, return, return-value

I want to create and return an object in a specific method. I get passed an integer in the method, and I know it will be 0, 1 or 2.

So fundamentally I would structure it like:

```
if num == 0 {
    return 12
} else if num == 1 {
    return 24
} else if num == 2 {
    return 36
}
```

Which *I know* would cover every circumstance.

But the compiler would complain that this doesn't cover every specific circumstance and I'd get an error. I need an `else` statement of some sort.

But what do I put as the else statement? I can't think of anything valid that would make sense. I could just change the last condition to an else, but it's not as clear later that it actually refers to a 2. It doesn't seem maintainable.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove the if from the last statement and leave the `else` only:

```
if num == 0 {
    return 12
} else if num == 1 {
    return 24
} else {
    return 36
}
```

But I'd rather use a `switch` statement:

```
switch(num) {
case 0: return 12
case 1: return 24
case 2: fallthrough
default: return 36
}
```

Here the `2` case is handled by the `default` case, using the `fallthrough` keyword

An alternative way to achieving the same, taking into account that the possible values are consecutive and starting from 0, is using an array:

```
let values = [12, 24, 36]
return values[num]
```

If the function is a class/struct method, the `values` array can be defined as a static (class) property outside the function, just to avoid instantiating it for each function call.
**Note** that this solution generates a runtime exception if the `num` value is not in the [0, 2] range

Answer (score 1):

You can't eat your cake and have it to.  If it obvious then an else is fine.  If it is not obvious, then you could use an enumeration so that the three options are unambiguously constrained.

For the former, you could use a trailing comment and assertion - that is probably the simplest:

```
assert(num >= 0 && num <= 2)
if num == 0 {
    return 12
} else if num == 1 {
    return 24
} else { // case that num == 2
    return 36
}
```

or use an enum type in a switch statement, and the compiler will know that there are only three cases and that you've covered them all.  You can use the toRaw() method as needed and base your enum type on an Int to facilitate that.

I imagine your actual case is a little more complicated than the one you presented, but the approaches remain unchanged.

Comment: I use the `assert` in cases like this.  I would probably just `assert(num == 2)` in the `else` case since that is the only place we're making an assumption.

Answer (score 0):

i would do `case` with exception

```
case num of
  0 -> ...
  1 -> ...
  2 -> ...
  otherwise -> throw exception('unsupported value')
end
```

compiler will be happy and your code will be clean. in some languages you can go even further and change num to Enumerator. then you will have same structure of `case` but withoutl the `otherwise` part. and compiler will warn you every time you decide to add new value for your enumerator but forget to add the new case in your function